# Docker problems on external drive

Tags: docker, external-hdd

I am having a weird problem with my laptop Dell XPS 13, when I run Docker from an external hard drive.

I have configured docker daemon with the following parameters

```
/usr/bin/docker daemon -g /path/to/exthd --storage-driver=devicemapper --storage-opt dm.basesize=90G -H fd://
```

The problem I experience is that my whole system freezes when the Docker container experiences heavy load (eg, kernel compilation). It seems that the hard drive is powered off, because no lights are shown. I cannot even log into a terminal to reboot the system!

At the beginning, I thought this may be a hardware issue. However

- I tried four external hard drives, still the same problem => it is not the hard drive.
- I disabled USB 3 with a special cable, still the same problem => it is not USB 3.
- I tried the external hard drive under heavy load, compiling kernels and moving huge files (without docker). The problem is not shown => there is not a problem due to hard disk heavy load.

Some information:

- kernel 4.6.1 (I also tried with 4.4.12)
- All partitions I tried were NTFS
- Docker version 1.11.2

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with ext4 rather than NTFS.  Just to remove one variable!

Comment: NTFS does not seem the best of the ideas. have a look too https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stephen Harris and Raul F Ribero said, NTFS is not a good choice for Docker. The problem was fixed when I used an external hard drive with an ext4 partition.